# RRAS and Internal vSwitch to access the internet not working

Tags: hyper-v, rras, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Sorry to ask but I have been doing my head in for 2 weeks now trying to figure this out by googling and clicking buttons by my self.

I have a new server installed Windows Server 2012 R2 (this is my 'host')
I installed the Hyper-V role and created a external and a internal switch.

I was following a few websites tutorials to install RRAS and configure it

- enable it, select NAT, select the external switch and finish - internal switch now 'should' have access to the internet.

My home routers IP is `192.168.0.1`
My host has a static IP assigned as `192.168.0.2`

I set my internal vSwitch IP address to `10.0.0.1` with dns server as the host `192.168.0.2`

Now I created a new Windows Server 2012 R2, gave it a static IP address `10.0.0.2`
I can ping the vSwitch (`10.0.0.1`), the host (`192.168.0.2`), the router (`192.168.0.1`) and ... [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

So I thought HELL YEAH... but I cant actually load [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in the browser.

So then I have been attempting to add a firewall rule to make it work but it won't work.... I have a feeling it's something to do with the **RRAS settings** > **IPv4** > **NAT** > **external vSwitch settings** and enable **HTTP** and **HTTPS** under **Services** and **Ports**.

I am not sure what I need to place in 'private address' so I tried `10.0.0.1` and `192.168.0.2`

Still cant go to google.com and I'm stuck and frustrated, can you help my please guys?

I really hope I made sense sorry if I have not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to ping www.google.com , you're all set. Services and ports part is only for port forwarding from outside to inside.

You should check your antivirus on the host. Easiest way is to disable it and try again. If it works, you can look for the specific setting.

Comment: You Sir are Amazing! I cant believe it was that! FFS so many hours! Thank you so much!